# Pandas SUMIFS, row dependant filters

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to do SUMIFS style calculations with pandas. Power Pivots DAX has the CALCULATE function which works perfectly but doesn't scale to millions of rows.

As simple example would be using the DataFrame to calculate the Cumulative Total column:

```
 Index  Customer  Spend Date         Cumulative Total
 0      A       100     16/08/2017      280
 1      A       50      15/08/2017      180
 2      B       30      15/08/2017      165
 3      A       50      14/08/2017      130
 4      B       75      14/08/2017      135
 5      C       60      14/08/2017      80
 6      A       80      13/08/2017      80
 7      B       60      13/08/2017      60
 8      C       20      12/08/2017      20
```

Ive tried apply a function over the rows but it is very slow, df would be the dataframe above:

```
def cumulativeSpend(row):
    returnvalue = df['Spend'][
            (df['Customer']==row['Customer'])
        &   (df['Date'] <= row['Date'])
        ].sum()
    return returnvalue
```

The rows are unordered, there might be a way using groupby but if there is I haven't figured out how to adjust it so the date is <= each row.

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, `sort_values` on `Date` first, then `cumsum` on `Spend` for `Customer` groups

```
In [160]: (df.sort_values('Date')
             .groupby('Customer')['Spend']
             .transform('cumsum')
             .sort_index())
     ...:
Out[160]:
0    280
1    180
2    165
3    130
4    135
5     80
6     80
7     60
8     20
Name: Spend, dtype: int64
```

Details

```
In [161]: df['cumtot'] = (df.sort_values('Date')
                            .groupby('Customer')['Spend']
                            .transform('cumsum')
                            .sort_index())

In [162]: df
Out[162]:
  Customer  Spend       Date  Cumulative Total  cumtot
0        A    100 2017-08-16               280     280
1        A     50 2017-08-15               180     180
2        B     30 2017-08-15               165     165
3        A     50 2017-08-14               130     130
4        B     75 2017-08-14               135     135
5        C     60 2017-08-14                80      80
6        A     80 2017-08-13                80      80
7        B     60 2017-08-13                60      60
8        C     20 2017-08-12                20      20
```

Note: If your `Date` column is string, then

```
In [158]: df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: beat me by a minute! Same basic approach though.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
df['Cumulative Spend'] = df.sort_values(by='Date').groupby('Customer')['Spend'].cumsum()
```

Sorting by date gets ascending order (note: if they're text rather than actual datetimes, this may fail). We group by `'Customer'` and apply a cumulative sum to `'Spend'`.

Comment: Nice, maybe first step `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)` should be

Comment: Thanks so much,  ill looking into the transform function as well

Comment: Do you know if using .groupby('Customer')['Spend'] actually creates the full grouping or just the spend column,
i.e what would the difference be between yours and :
df[['Customer','Spend']].groupby('Customer').cumsum()
assuming it is already sorted